# How to auto save Id(unique no) retrieved from database, in android

Tags: android, autosave

I am currently working on a android application, where I want to save the login details. I am using a unique id (primary key auto increment in mysql table) to uniquely retrieve the details from the table. I am using this id has a login attribute. How to make it as auto login or, when the user enters the login page, the id should be already present?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SQLITE DB` for this. When user login than data will be save in `SQLITE DB`. Sorry I couldn't comment. I have low reputation..